# unable to run selenium2 suite in testNG

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am not able to run test suite in eclipse with testNG for selenium2. 
TestNG appears to run, but the Total tests run is always 0.
I am able to run this test from eclipse directly with selenium2 (run as->java application). 
I am able to test the testNG for a small program with @Test, @BeforeMethod,@AfterMethod annotations
kindly help me
xml  file contents

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="WikiPedia test" verbose="3" parallel="methods" >

<test name="wiki">
    <classes>
    <class name="com.programs.WebDriverTest" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: "run as->java application" or "run as -> testng test" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Run As...TestNG Test, not as Java application.